# Three dimensional scatter plot in R through car package

Tags: r, graph

I'm trying to make three dimensional scatter plot in `R` through `car` package. MWE is given below.

```
pdf(file = "Hyperellipsoid.pdf")
library(car)
scatter3d(
    prestige ~ income + education
  , xlab = ""
  , ylab = ""
  , zlab = ""
  , surface=FALSE
  , fill=FALSE
  , grid=TRUE
  , axis.scales=FALSE
  , ellipsoid=TRUE
  , axis.col= "white"
  , square.col= "white"
  , point.col = "white"
  , data=Duncan
  )
dev.off()
```

[image]

**Questions**

1. How to remove data circles from the plot?
2. How to save the plot as pdf format?

Comment: [maybe useful?](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-June/243413.html)

Comment: Thanks @user1317221_G for your comment. Would you mind to shed more light on your comment? Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 the comment means you need to hack the function `scatter3d` to avoid the call to `rgl.points`...

Comment: @agstudy and @user1317221_G, how can I seen the code of `scatter3d`? I tried `UseMethod("scatter3d")` but without any success.

Comment: A quick (but incomplete fix would ahve been: `sphere.size=0,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to hack the full scatterplot function (which you can see more easily via `car:::scatter3d.default`); you can just use `car:::ellipsoid`.

```
library("car")
dmat <- subset(Duncan,select=c(income,education,prestige))
dfn <- 3
dfd <- nrow(Duncan) - 1
level <- 0.95
ell.radius <- sqrt(dfn * qf(level, dfn, dfd))
library("rgl")
open3d()
rgl.material(color="blue")
ellips <- car:::ellipsoid(center = colMeans(dmat),
            shape = cov(dmat),
            radius = ell.radius)
wire3d(ellips)
rgl.postscript("ell3d.pdf",fmt="pdf")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that changing the color points don't get an effect. A solution is to hack the function. I give in the follwing how I do generally when I want to hack some R functions. So this is a general answer on how to hack a function four your custom use.

1. `capture.output(getS3method('scatter3d','default'),file='my.scatter3d.R')` . This will create a new file with the function.
2. Then, you open the file and you remove the last 2 lines. You give a name to the function. for example: `my.scatter3d`
3. Change the lines where you call `rgl.points`.
4. finally you call the function like this :

   ```
    source('my.scatter3d.R')
    scatter3d(
           z= Duncan$prestige 
           x= Duncan$income ,
           y = Duncan$education,
           ....
   ```

If you nwant to call the scatter formula function, you need to hack ...

```
  `capture.output(getS3method('scatter3d','formula'),file='my.scatter3dformlua.R')`
```

and change the line

```
  scatter3d(X[, 2], X[, 1], X[, 3], xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
            zlab = zlab, labels = labels, radius = radius, ...)
```

with

```
  my.scatter3d(X[, 2], X[, 1], X[, 3], xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
            zlab = zlab, labels = labels, radius = radius, ...)
```

**PS**

If the function complain to not find a function, generally we add the package name as anemspace,
for example:

```
 rgl:::FUNCTION_
```